# Django project set up with MySql and virtual environment from start

Tags: django, django-mysql

I am new to django so I need to start with django projects..I need information regarding how to start with django project using MySql database and virtual environment on Linux.

Comment: now what was the your problem

Comment: django==1.10.5,mysqlclient,django-mysql these are the packages required

Comment: Actually I have django installed in my pc but I  am unaware of commands to  start with django project with MySQL and virtual env.

Comment: django-admin --help this command shows all commands with usage

Answer (score 1):

Technically you don't need to start with those things, and you can swap environments and databases at a later stage, but it does make things a bit easier if you set those up at the start.

Assuming you are on Linux, and have Mysql installed on your system.

1: 
Create a virtual environment (there are plenty of tutorials around about this), but something like this (after creating a directory where you wnat teh virtualenv):

```
virtualenv --no-site-packages . -p /usr/bin/python3.5
```

No site packages shouldn't be needed unless you are using an old version, and you only need the -p to specify a different version form the default one on your system. Like I say there are plenty of tutorials to get the details.

2: 
Activate you virtual environment. The last command created it, but it isn't being used. Installing it should have created some folders, bin, include, lib, lib64.

```
. bin/activate
```

Your command line prompt should change at this point.

Basically this sets some environmental variables so that any python command are now using the python and libraries from your virtual environment.

3. install Django and Mysql python libraries.

   pip install Django, mysqlclient,django-mysql

You are now ready to start a Django project - just do as you normally would. You say you have done it before without a virtualenv. The important part is to activate the virtual environment before doing any work on the project, otherwise you will be issuing commands to the system Python and not your virtualenv.

With MySQL you will need to create users and the database that you want to use with your project manually (again plenty of resources out there to show you how to do that). Then change the settings in settings.py to point to your database with that user.

Answer (score 0):

Follow any of these tutorials and you will be able to setup django with mysql database:

- https://www.leeboonstra.com/developer/setup-a-django-project-with-a-mysql-database/
- https://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/07/how-set-django-mysql-ubuntu-hardy/